# How can I query for root entities in the App Engine DataStore (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write a query which will identify and return all root entities (i.e. entities which have no ancestor). I initially tried calling `Query.setAncestor(null)` but later found out from the [datastore Query docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html) that this doesn't work:

> Passing null as a parameter to Query.setAncestor(String ancestor) does not query for entities without ancestors (this type of query is not currently supported).

So now I'm a bit stuck, given what the Query API contains I can't figure out how one would construct a query which identified all the root entities.

This needs to be app functionality so I'm looking for a solution which works programatically as opposed to some manual intervention wnich requires me to log in to the admin console and click a button :-)

Anyone know how to do this?

Cheers,

Edd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a property to your models that you can query on.  Perhaps a boolean named `is_root` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Robert, this seems sensible. I had wondered whether I should create a special _root_ ancestor and set it to root entities but I think your suggestion is far simpler, and doesn't mess up the ancestry/ path of the Entities. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation indicates, there's no way to do this - other than working around it as @Robert suggests. If you tell us what you're trying to achieve - as opposed to how you're trying to achieve it - perhaps we can provide a suggestion on how best to go about it.

Comment: Hi Nick, apologies if that wasn't clear in the initial post - I thought I had specified exactly what I was trying to achieve without any of the how :-) To re-iterate what I'm trying achieve: I'm trying to obtain a list of all the root level entities in my app's datastore. Anyway, as you mentioned @Robert's answer is appropriate here and should serve my purpose for this. Thanks.

Comment: @Edd What I mean is, to what end are you doing this? If you're trying to do this sort of query, it indicates that perhaps your data model isn't ideal, and we might be able to suggest an alternative way to model your data that works better.

Comment: @NickJohnson I'd love such a suggestion. My structure is such that I have `Tag` root-level entities that represent the community's tags/labels and a subclass of `UserTag` who's parent is a user (custom entity, not a real `User` object). I'd like to query for all community tags and would rather not have them in the same entity group as many users could potentially be adding/editing tags simultaneously. Any recommendations on how to structure it and any recommendations on further reading for conceptually structuring datastore data in general would be hugely appreciated.